# Can anyone explain me the output of the below recursion?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I think the last output should be 5 but it is 6, why?, Kindly explain very simply

```
def tri_recursion(k):
  if(k > 0):
    result = k + tri_recursion(k - 1)
    print(result)
  else:
    result = 0
  return result

print("Recursion Example Results")
tri_recursion(3)
```

output is -
Recursion Example Results
1
3
6

Desired output is -
Recursion Example Results
1
3
5

I was expecting the answer to be 5 but its 6 in the last

Comment: Can you explain why would you expect 5?

Comment: Sorry, I got it! :)

At first I thought the recursion was to be 3 + (3-1) = 5
but now I got it!
recusrion happens this way, 
3 + (3-1) + (2-1) = 6

Comment: Well `0 + 1 = 1` then `1 + 2 = 3` then `3 + 3 = 6`

Comment: Your code basically sums all natural numbers from `k` down to `1`... `3+2+1` is `6`

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I got it! :)

At first I thought the recursion would happen this way, 3 + (3-1) = 5
but now I got it!
recusrion happens this way,
3 + (3-1) + (2-1) + (1-1) = 63

This way we can solve the factorial of any natural number

```
 def fact_(n):
   if n == 0:
     return 1
   else:
     return n*fact_(n-1)


fact_(5)
```

Comment: Small Tip regarding recursion! 
Stop thinking about all the steps and states of the function calls. It will give you much more clarity and save confusion. 
Instead, assume and trust your function knows what to do for `n-1`, and just think if the function knows how to handle `n`.
Also, verify the stopping condition.
In your example, `factorial(n)` is actually `n*(n-1)*(n-2)*....*1`. Assuming your function works for `factorial(n-1)`, you just need to multiply the result by `n`.
And by "Mathematical induction" this should work always.

Comment: Please include your personal statements inside the comment section. Your answer segment must be clear and just focuses on the answer itself, not any other statements such as apologies about your misunderstandings. Thank you.

Comment: @FatemehSangin I am new to stack, sorry if it hurts you personally.